# Can't right click to change an event's color on Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I used to edit my events' colors on Google calendar by right-clicking the event to choose a different color.

But that feature seems to have gone for me?? Now I have to click the event, click edit, and then change the colors in the event page rather than the overview page.

Is it really an update from Google Calendar's site or some of my settings went wrong?

Comment: It just got fixed today. Guess it was Google's issue.